# Understanding the definition of homeomorphism?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am reading *Real Mathematical Analysis* by Pugh and I have just encountered the definition of homeomorphism. He gives the following figure to show how a triangle and circle might be homeomorphic:

[image]

My question is, in this (and for example the coffe cup $\to$ doughnut example) are we considering the circle/triangle as subests of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (or $\mathbb{R}^3$), with the same, inherited, metric? Or are we considering the distance between two points on the circle as, for example, the length of the arc connecting them?

Comment: Subsets of $\mathbb R^2$ (or $\mathbb R^3$) equipped with subspace topology. If it concerns topology 'pur sang' then metrics are not relevant.

Comment: I think if you actually write out the homeomorphism (it suffices to show that a chord of the circle is homeomorphic to its subtended arc), you will see how which topology you are working in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For homeomorphism the metric doesn't matter - only the topology it induces counts.

In each of the examples you cite the embeddings provide a metric which determines the topology of each object 
<s>arclength for the plane pictures</s>. The indicated distortion in the space in which the objects are embedded tells you how to construct the continuous bijection between the objects that provides the homeomorphism.

**Edit.** The circle and the triangle are not isometric (when each has the metric induced by its embedding). The triangle contains degenerate triangles (three points on the same edge) while the circle has none.

Comment: The inherited metric doesn't coincide with the arclength, but they generate the same topology on the circle (with the open arcs as basic open sets).

Comment: @Berci Right you are.. Edited to strike out the false assertion.

Comment: Finally have time to return to this question... Thanks for the answer; however, I do not know much about Topology; I am just skimming over and doing exercises in Pugh's Real Analysis. Therefore I couldn't really understand your answer. So for someone only familiar with metric spaces, is it wrong to think of the square and the circle as having the same $\mathbb{R}^2$ metric?

Comment: The phrase "the same $\mathbb{R}^2$ metric" makes no sense. A square and a circle in the plane each have a metric inherited from the usual metric in the plane. It may or may not be possible to map one to the other isometrically, but that does not matter when thinking about homeomorphism.   In  the example in your question the indicated map between circle and triangle is continuous in both directions but does not preserve Euclidean distances.nor distances measured along the curves.

Comment: I think I see your objection; I was using "metric" too informally. Of course they do not have the same metric, because a metric is a function; and the circle and square are not the same set, so any functions defined on them are necessarily different. But yeah I meant that both sets have the inherited metric from $\mathbb{R}^2$. And thanks, now I understand that the metric spaces are homeomorphic but not isometric.

Comment: Also one more thing if you don't mind; you say that "The indicated distortion in the space in which the objects are embedded tells you how to construct the continuous bijection between the objects that provides the homeomorphism". It appears that to do the mapping, you draw rays from the center of the triangle and map it in the obvious way. However, I imagine you could also draw lines perpendicular to the sides of the triangle and map it in that way, right? Is the author's way given because it is easier to convert it to algebra, or is there no reason to prefer one over the other?

Comment: @Ovi You're welcome. Interesting question: when is there an isometry between a circle and a square in the plane, each taken with the inherited metric? Perhaps never. It's clearly impossible unless the diameter of the circle equals the diagonal of the square (look for maximum distance between points).

Comment: @Ovi Yes, you've described a different homeomorphism. Neither one is particularly interesting. Neither would be worth converting to formal algebra. The whole point of the picture is to illustrate the idea. Which it has now done for you.

Comment: Many thanks again; I also came up with that method of showing there is never in isometry; the square has two pairs of points of maximum distance; the circle has infinitely many such pairs.